# After Migration my Website is not opening

Tags: php, .htaccess

My Site is http://homeodisha.com/

After migration to a different server its not opening "500 Internal Server Error"

My Base location is "/home/odisha/public_html"

Below is my .htaccess file

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

# enable apache morRewrite module #
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Google and Yahoo sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /plugins/sitemap/sitemap.php?search=google [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^yahoo-sitemap.txt$ /plugins/sitemap/sitemap.php?search=yahoo [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^urllist.txt$ /plugins/sitemap/sitemap.php?search=urllist [QSA,L] 

# define system languages
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.{2})?/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# define paging
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/index([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&pg=$3 [QSA,L]

# define listing
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/(.*)-l([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&listing_id=$3 [QSA,L]

# define single pages
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(^/*)?.ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# define other pages
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/?(.*)?(.ht(m?ml?)|/+)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server's error logs?

Comment: yes I have access

Comment: Did you verify whether the error is caused by your .htaccess? Did you uncomment the first line for testing?

Comment: Then look into the error log - there will be a verbose error message there.

Comment: in the error log there is no error

Comment: There must be. A 500 is always logged somewhere. Are you sure you have the right file?

Comment: 1. Look at your http error log.  There's almost certainly an error there.  2. Look at your http access log and operating system logs, too.  3. Failing all else, modify php.ini to enable verbose logging.

Comment: you are looking in the wrong log then.  There is an error somewhere.

Comment: Shall I share my site login details so that after experiment I would change this?

Ok, After deleting the htaccess file I am getting below error

Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_f20_0.MYI' (Errcode: 122)

Comment: /home/odisha/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server confi

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

Comment: Meisam Mulla - My first thought was "WTF"?  But you're right: that "php_flag" line doesn't belong in an .htaccess file - it could well be the whole problem!  Good call!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Substitute a simple "hello world" .html file in the root; see if you can open that.
2. If you can display a minimal .html file, then try a .php file containing only "phpinfo ();".  Make sure that displays.  Make sure all the things you need (for example, mysql support) are enabled in your PHP/Apache environment.
3. Look at your http error log. There's almost certainly an error there. Honest.
4. Also look at your http access log and operating system logs, too. They might give additional clues.
5. Failing all else, modify php.ini to enable verbose logging.
6. Do NOT worry about .htaccess until you're certain it's the culprit.
7. I suspect you'll find the actual problem somewhere before you even get to step 4).

Good luck!